# How to run maven project in IntelliJ that requires a file to be in class path?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I am studying this [book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Spring.productCd-1118893034.html) and I am having difficulty running the example code.

The code I causing the problem is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/wiley/beginningspring/ch2/ch2-beans.xml");
```

the error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [com/wiley/beginningspring/ch2/ch2-beans.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/wiley/beginningspring/ch2/ch2-beans.xml] cannot be opened because
>   it does not exist

What I tried is, in IntelliJ, imported the code as Maven Project and did clean install:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ xml-based-configuration ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/koraytugay/Downloads/spring-book-ch2/xml-based-configuration/target/xml-based-configuration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/koraytugay/.m2/repository/com/wiley/beginningspring/xml-based-configuration/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/xml-based-configuration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/koraytugay/Downloads/spring-book-ch2/xml-based-configuration/pom.xml to /Users/koraytugay/.m2/repository/com/wiley/beginningspring/xml-based-configuration/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/xml-based-configuration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Then I right click on the **main** method in **Main.java** and click run, but I am getting the error that

```
"/com/wiley/beginningspring/ch2/ch2-beans.xml"
```

is not found in classpath. What is the right way to solve this?

My run configuration is as follows:

[image]

**Edit 01:**
I can make the example work like this but I want to understand the classpath solution:

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/Users/koraytugay/Downloads/spring-book-ch2/xml-based-configuration/src/main/java/com/wiley/beginningspring/ch2/ch2-beans.xml");
```

**Edit 02:**
The solution that also worked:
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot when you drop-down main, or better yet, find where they are setting the XML file, and change the path to point it to where you have it.

Comment: @WeareBorg What do you mean drop-down main? I edited the question for your second suggestion but I really want to understand the classpath solution and want to make it work somehow..

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you are under the impression that setting a working directory will influence what is on the classpath or not? Because it does not.

Comment: @Gimby I did not set the working directory myself, it was default by IntelliJ.

Comment: Okay let me rephrase, are you under the impression that intellij does this to set the classpath? Because it does not.

Comment: Oh, that Main thing is one file only, ok, I thought it is like a package or something, so I said drop it down meaning, open it. Did you try changing the path of the XML file... Why does your path starts from /Users. If you are on windows, it should be from C: and if on Linux, it should be from /home/username. Anyways, right click on project, open module settings, go in Modules on left, and on right side, go in paths. You will see output path, paste your XML in Filesystem at that path.

Comment: @Gimby No, I have no idea what that working directory is. I added it to the question because I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: @WeareBorg I am using OS X. I think in OS X it goes like "/Users/koraytugay/..." Can you please see my Edit 02? It worked liked this, thanks a lot. Can you provide an answer why this works so I can understand what is going on and also accept it?

Comment: @WeareBorg Also, how can I make this work from command line? Without using the IDE?

Comment: I am making an answer for you.

Comment: So, all set?? Did you read the answer?

Comment: @WeareBorg Sorry I went for dinner :) I am reading the answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically resources wouldn't be put in `src/main/java`, but rather `src/main/resources`.  `resources` contains files that [Maven will copy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) to the classpath of the build artifact.  `java` contains files that aren't copied to the build artifact (the `.java` files aren't copied to the artifact, so neither will your XML file be)

Try moving `ch2-beans.xml` from `main` to `resources` while preserving the rest of the path.

Comment: When I move the file to /resources folder I need to modify the code as follows: new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/resources/ch2-beans.xml"); What do you mean preserve the path?

Comment: @KorayTugay: I'd really need a better idea of your Maven configuration, but if you're using a vanilla config then items in `/src/main/resources` should be on the project (and artifact's) classpath, so `/src/main/resources/ch2-beans.xml` should be available on the classpath using just `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/ch2-beans.xml")`.  If that's not working you'll need to provide a self-contained example of your configuration (including your project folder layout and relevant parts of the `pom.xml`) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the file you would just put at the beginning:

```
@ComponentScan("com.wiley.beginningspring")
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:ch2-beans.xml")})
```

and it will search anywhere in the classpath.

With a class variable:

```
@Resource
private Environment env;
```

get the content of the file like:

```
String yourPropertyValue = env.getRequiredProperty("your_property_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

So, when you compile Java code, .class files are created. The classpath where are your .class files going to be located which the JVM will use and run your code for you. The reason why I told you to go to the module settings->modules-->path was there you can see the compile output path where your .class files are located. There JVM was easily able to find your .xml file and get information from it.

Answering your 2nd question, how to use it without IDE. If you just have one Java file, its simple :

open your Mac OS X terminal. change directory to project where you have your java file. Now give command :

```
javac filename.java
```

Now javac meaning the compiler will compile your file. and create a binary called filename. You can simply execute it by saying

```
java filename
```

Note, I didn't gave extension 2nd time, as its a binary file now. If there are multiple java files, you can use :

```
javac filename1.java filenam2.java
```

I would not recommend using just console, for advanced stuff you would require an IDE. Any doubts, lemme know.